# Баг PDO при выдаче результата SELECT

Tags: pdo, php, sql

Доброго всем времени суток. Вчера столкнулся с необъяснимой проблемой и грешу на PDO с которым я лишь недавно познакомился. И так есть простейший SELECT запрос

```
$this->sql = 'SELECT * FROM plugins';
$this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare($this->sql);
```

ИЛИ

```
$this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare($this->sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
```

Далее

```
$this->STH->execute();
```

И собственно передача результата:
Либо так

```
$rows = $this->STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Либо так:

```
while($row = $this->STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}
```

И всё в общем-то работает, по индексу я могу обратиться к каждому элементу **$rows**, но, если я напишу такое **print_r($rows);** то распечатывается только информация со 2 индекса, а первого будто и нет. **bool(false)** вот такую вещь я смог узнать о первом элементе. Если это поможет, то в каждую ячейку **$rows[]** записывается отдельный массив и один из элементов этого массива сериализован (serialize).

Comment: [Не утверждайте, что нашли ошибку](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#itsabug)

Comment: А var_dump() тоже со 2-го выводит? И как вы узнали, что первый равен false? Из вывода print_r? И лучше приведите код, где вы пытаетесь что-то сделать с результатом после его получения

Comment: С помощью var_dump() я увидел что массив с индексом 0 равен bool(false), при том что можно было свободно написать print_r($rows[0]); и получить значение. Собственно, сразу после while я и делал этот вывод.